# Can you limit the number or type of connections between shapes in Visio?

Tags: vba, visio

I would like to create custom shapes in Visio representing OEM connectors, and create rules about how they can be connected.

For example, make it impossible to draw a male-to-male connection, or make it impossible to draw a connection between a 2-pin and a 4-pin connector. Is that possible in Visio?

Comment: This might be a better question to ask on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) (please verify their posting rules first), since Stack Overflow is more focused on much more tangible programming problems.

Answer (score 0):

In Visio, out of the box, generally speaking, you cannot prevent the user from drawing an incorrect diagram. But you can validate it afterward giving meaningful messages. It is pretty complex, you need to use specific formulas and other stuff. There is a good book from David Parker, discussing validation opportunities in Visio, "Microsoft Visio 2013 Business Process Diagramming and Validation".

In some cases I think a code solution (such as custom Visio extension) could be easier to implement than some complex validation rules; you could consider going this direction as well. Visio extension has access to the drawing and can validate the diagram user draws in real time, responding to drawing actions and notifying the user on errors. But this basically means that you write a lot of custom code that integrates with Visio.